# web.config breaks the themes for sub-directory multisite

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting

We are converting a single wordpress site to a sub-directory network but we can't find any web.config that works correctly. We can never get the theme to work, not even on the root (/) site, as soon as we change the single-site web.config for a multisite one it breaks.

I have been searching for hours and have found several topics where people have found a web.config that works but none works for us, the theme is always broken.

The setup we want is this:

http://www.domain.com/ (main site)
http://www.domain.com/en/ (English version of the site)

I did get it working to an extent on my own Apache server except it tried looking for media in /en/media/ when it should just have been /media/. However the host we use use IIS apparently.

**Here is one web.config I've tried which lets me access the dashboard for all sites and everything seems to work except for the theme**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="wp-includes/ms-files.php?file={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 7" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is the web.config that the Wordpress network setup page suggest, this one makes the /en/ site dashboard 404:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Neither works. Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked our hosting provider for help and they modified the first web.config to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
<!--    <security>
      <authentication>
        <basicAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
      </authentication>
    </security>-->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="wp-includes/ms-files.php?file={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
<add input="{URL}" pattern="([a-zA-Z0-9\./_-]+)\.axd" />
</conditions>
 <action type="None" />
 </rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 7" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>




      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```